# I can't get any data form my Google-Fit. I don't know how to build this query in c#

Tags: c#, google-fit, google-apis-explorer

I have Credentials and I was authorized. Then i want to get Data(for ex. weight or steps). 
https://keestalkstech.com/2016/07/getting-your-weight-from-google-fit-with-c/ 
I tried this code, but initially had problems with time, then I had a nullable array, but in my account I have all information for a particular day(steps, updated weight). So then I tried to build request on developers.google.com but ERROR 400 (Bad Request):

```
#1
{
  "application": {
    "name": "MyCare"
  },
  "dataType": {
    "field": [
      {
        "format": "integerList",
        "name": "steps"
      }
    ],
    "name": "com.google.step_count.delta"
  },
  "device": {
    "manufacturer": "MyCare",
    "model": "xiaomi",
    "type": "phone",
    "uid": "",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "type": "derived"
}

#2
{
  "application": {
    "name": "MyCare"
  },
  "dataType": {
    "field": [
      {
        "format": "integerList",
        "name": "weight"
      }
    ],
    "name": "com.google.weight"
  },
  "device": {
    "manufacturer": "",
    "model": "",
    "type": "phone",
    "uid": "",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "type": "derived"
}
```

And i used userId "me". But when i tried to use clientId whith which one i was authorized i had an ERROR 403 "Unauthorized"....

How should I do this query or maybe there are some other variants to get data in c#. I use Google.Apis.Fitness.v1 and create a Fitness Service:

```
var service = new FitnessService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = ApplicationName});
..}
```

I also found such way, but I have nullable array. I think this way is not correct, so help me to redo it:

```
var service = new FitnessService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = ApplicationName});
            var dataSets = service.Users.Dataset.Aggregate(
    new AggregateRequest
    {
        AggregateBy = new[] {
        new AggregateBy {DataTypeName = "com.google.location.sample"}}
    }, "me")
    .ExecuteAsync();
            var result = dataSets.Result;
        }
```

Pls, help! I need to do it in 3 hours :(((
But a have this problem for 2 mounth.

Comment: then its not authorized.. we cant do much about that

Comment: @LizaKaufman you can [edit] your question.

Comment: @BugFinder but I'm authorized and on my Google Fit i see my app. I don't know how i can get data in c# ...

Comment: Do you have `[Authorize]` like in snippet 3.2 here: https://keestalkstech.com/2016/07/offline-google-authentication-for-mvc-net/ ?

Comment: @barbsan No, now i'll try, thank u